# ASP.NET insert form data into SQL Server database doesn't work

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

I am writing an empty webform application using ASP.NET 4.5 and I have a problem with inserting data from my form, that I made, into my SQL Server database table. I think all the code is good but it doesn't work. Also I need to make a cookie on this page but that neither works. Can you please help me? I work with Master pages and content pages. The problem is with my content page I think.

My HTML code of the page is:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <p id="p">Vul hier je gegevens en je nieuwe score in!</p>

    <table style="width: 100%;" id="table">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">Voornaam:</td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtVoornaam" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style6">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style8">Datum:</td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDatum" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDatum" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Onjuiste datum!" MaximumValue="01-01-2020" MinimumValue="01-01-1990" Type="Date">!</asp:RangeValidator>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDatum" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Datum niet ingevoerd!">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">Achternaam:</td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAchternaam" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style6">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAchternaam" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Het veld &quot;Achternaam&quot; is verplicht!">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style8">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">Categorie:</td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Kinderen</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Volwassenen</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style6">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Het veld &quot;Categorie&quot; is verplicht!">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style8">Score:</td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtScore" runat="server" Width="60px"></asp:TextBox>
                    &nbsp;punten</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtScore" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Onjuist aantal punten!" MaximumValue="300" MinimumValue="1" Type="Integer">!</asp:RangeValidator>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtScore" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Score niet ingevuld!">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style4">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style6">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style8">Afstand:</td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAfstand" runat="server" Width="60px"></asp:TextBox>
                    &nbsp;meter</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAfstand" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Onjuist aantal meters!" MaximumValue="1000" MinimumValue="1" Type="Integer">!</asp:RangeValidator>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAfstand" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Afstand niet ingevuld!">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">Soort Boog:</td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Recurve">Recurve</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Compount">Compount</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Long Bow">Long Bow</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Flat Bow">Flat Bow</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style6">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList1" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Het veld &quot;Soort Boog&quot; is verplicht!">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style8">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style4">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style6">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style8">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="125px" />
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMelding" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style6">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style8">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ForeColor="White" HeaderText="U heeft een foutmelding!" Height="76px" ShowMessageBox="True" style="margin-bottom: 0px" />
</asp:Content>
```

And my `aspx.cs` code is:

```
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // validaties!!

        if (Page.IsValid)// de validaties zijn goed afgerond
        {
            // geselecteerde waarde van de RadioButtonList opslaan in Boog
            string boog = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;

            // alleen de geselecteerde waarde van de DropDownList opslaan in Categorie
            char categorie = Convert.ToChar(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);

            // datum wordt de systeemdatum
            DateTime datum = DateTime.Today;

            // naar database schrijven!!
            int score = Convert.ToInt16(txtAfstand.Text);
            int afstand = Convert.ToInt16(txtAfstand.Text);

            string conString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["csScore"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString);

            string sqlOpdracht = "INSERT INTO t_ScoreToevoegen(ID, Voornaam, Achternaam, Boog, Categorie, Datum, Score, Afstand) value (@ID ,@Voornaam, @Achternaam, @Boog, @Categorie, @Datum, @Score, @Afstand)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlOpdracht, conn);

            // alle waarden in parameters zetten.
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Voornaam", txtVoornaam.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Achternaam", txtAchternaam.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Boog", boog);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Categorie", categorie);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum", datum);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", txtScore.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Afstand", txtAfstand.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 7000);

            try
            {
                // open de connectie
                conn.Open();

                // voer opdracht uit en geef aan hoeveel rijen zijn toegevoegd
                int aantalRijen = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                lblMelding.Text = aantalRijen.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                // foutmelding
                lblMelding.Text = err.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                // connectie sluiten
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        // cookie!!
        // maak een nieuw HttpCookie Object
        HttpCookie koekje = new HttpCookie("userinfo");

        // Voeg de stukje tekst aan de inhoud van de cookie toe met als naam usernaam
        koekje["voornaam"] = txtVoornaam.Text;
        koekje["achternaam"] = txtAchternaam.Text;
        koekje["categorie"] = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        koekje["boog"] = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
        koekje["datum"] = txtDatum.Text;
        koekje["score"] = txtScore.Text;
        koekje["afstand"] = txtAfstand.Text;

        // zet de houdbaarheidsdatum op 1 uur na nu
        koekje.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);

        // schrijf de cookie weg naar schijf
        Response.SetCookie(koekje);

        //roep een volgende .aspx pagina aan.

        Response.Redirect("~/ScoreToevoegenCookie.aspx");
    }
}
```

`Web.config`:

```
 <configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="csScore" connectionString="Data Source=VAIO;Initial Catalog=ASP.NET Boogschieten Final;Integrated Security=True" />
        <add name="ASP.NET Boogschieten FinalConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=VAIO;Initial Catalog=ASP.NET Boogschieten Final;Integrated Security=True" />
        </connectionStrings>
       <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>

  <appSettings>
   <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
   </appSettings>
   < /configuration>
```

And the page where the cookie needs to go to:

HTML:

```
  <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
       <table style="width: 100%;" id="table">
          <tr>
               <td class="auto-style1">Voornaam:</td>
               <td class="auto-style4">
                   <asp:Label ID="lblVoornaamCookie" runat="server" Text="...">   </asp:Label>
               </td>
               <td class="auto-style6">&nbsp;</td>
               <td class="auto-style8">Datum:</td>
               <td class="auto-style2">
                <asp:Label ID="lblDatumCookie" runat="server" Text="..."></asp:Label>
               </td>
               <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
               <td class="auto-style1">Achternaam:</td>
               <td class="auto-style4">
                   <asp:Label ID="lblAchternaamCookie" runat="server" Text="...">     </asp:Label>
               </td>
               <td class="auto-style6">
                &nbsp;</td>
               <td class="auto-style8">&nbsp;</td>
               <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
              <td class="auto-style1">Categorie:</td>
               <td class="auto-style4">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblCategorieCookie" runat="server" Text="..."></asp:Label>
              </td>
               <td class="auto-style4">
                &nbsp;</td>
               <td class="auto-style4">Score:</td>
               <td class="auto-style5">
                   <asp:Label ID="lblScoreCookie" runat="server" Text="..."></asp:Label>
                punten</td>
               <td class="auto-style4">
                &nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="auto-style4">&nbsp;</td>
               <td class="auto-style6">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="auto-style8">Afstand:</td>
               <td class="auto-style2">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblAfstandCookie" runat="server" Text="..."></asp:Label>
                meter</td>
              <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td class="auto-style1">Soort Boog:</td>
               <td class="auto-style4">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblBoogCookie" runat="server" Text="..."></asp:Label>
               </td>
               <td class="auto-style6">
                &nbsp;</td>
               <td class="auto-style8">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="auto-style4">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="auto-style6">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="auto-style8">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">
                <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="125px" />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <asp:Label ID="lblMelding" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style6">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style8">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

`aspx.cs`:

```
 public partial class ScoreToevoegenCookie : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // maak een cookie object
        HttpCookie koekje = Request.Cookies["userinfo"];

        // controleer of er een koekje met de naam userinfo bestaat.
        if (koekje != null)
        {

            // vul een label met de inhoud van usernaam en taal
            lblVoornaamCookie.Text = koekje["voornaam"];
            lblAchternaamCookie.Text = koekje["achternaam"];
            lblCategorieCookie.Text = koekje["categorie"];
            lblBoogCookie.Text = koekje["boog"];
            lblDatumCookie.Text = koekje["datum"];
            lblScoreCookie.Text = koekje["score"];
            lblAfstandCookie.Text = koekje["afstand"];

        }
        else //koekje = null
        {
            lblVoornaamCookie.Text = "Geen cookie gevonden";
            lblAchternaamCookie.Text = "Geen cookie gevonden";
            lblCategorieCookie.Text = "Geen cookie gevonden";
            lblBoogCookie.Text = "Geen cookie gevonden";
            lblDatumCookie.Text = "Geen cookie gevonden";
            lblScoreCookie.Text = "Geen cookie gevonden";
            lblAfstandCookie.Text = "Geen cookie gevonden";
        }       
    }
}
```

And all the validation are working!

Sorry for all the code! All this is in content pages!

Thanks!

Comment: Please describe what do you mean by "doesn't work". It throws an exception? Wrong data is inserted into database?

Comment: @kayson: There is no data added into my SQL database if I click (in the form that I made) on the save button. The data is supposed to be added into my SQL database but my application doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem :** You are using the keyword  `VALUE` instead of `VALUES` in `INSERT INTO` Statement.

**Solution:** You need to use Keyword `VALUES` in `INSERT INTO` statement

Please refer this link for [`INSERT INTO Syntax`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

Replace This:

```
string sqlOpdracht = "INSERT INTO t_ScoreToevoegen(ID, Voornaam, Achternaam,
                                     Boog, Categorie, Datum, Score, Afstand)        
   value (@ID ,@Voornaam, @Achternaam, @Boog, @Categorie, @Datum, 
                                                           @Score, @Afstand)";
```

With This:

```
string sqlOpdracht = "INSERT INTO t_ScoreToevoegen(ID, Voornaam, Achternaam,
                                 Boog, Categorie, Datum, Score, Afstand)        
   values (@ID ,@Voornaam, @Achternaam, @Boog, @Categorie, @Datum, 
   ^^^^^^^                                      @Score, @Afstand)";
```

Comment: Oke thanks for your answer. But I tried that but it still doesn't work. There are no rows added in my database. :S

Comment: @Marjolein: Okay, are you getting any error? if yes then please provide the error details.

Comment: No there is no error it just doesn't work :S I did run my application after replacing the code but there were no errors showed. And I clicked on save in my form but it didn't insert the data into my database.

Comment: @Marjolein: has it solved your problem, if not please uncheck it as answer.

Comment: @Marjolein: you should be able to see the exception details in `lblMelding` label.could you please debug and see.

Comment: oke sorry I unchecked it.

Comment: there are no exception details showed in lblMelding :S

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, though is the `ID` of your SQL table a primary key set to auto generate?

If so, the problem is likely that you're trying to add an ID, rather than letting SQL generate it for you. SQL won't allow you to insert this unless you `SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyDBName t_ScoreToevoegen ON`

So try changing this:

```
string sqlOpdracht = "INSERT INTO t_ScoreToevoegen(ID, Voornaam, Achternaam, Boog, Categorie, Datum, Score, Afstand) value (@ID ,@Voornaam, @Achternaam, @Boog, @Categorie, @Datum, @Score, @Afstand)";
```

To this - notice i removed all ID references - Also changed `value` to `values` per the other answer:

```
string sqlOpdracht = "INSERT INTO t_ScoreToevoegen(Voornaam, Achternaam, Boog, Categorie, Datum, Score, Afstand) values (@Voornaam, @Achternaam, @Boog, @Categorie, @Datum, @Score, @Afstand)";
```

And also remove this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 7000);
```

Comment: I tried that but that also doesn't work. :'( And there are no errors showed...

Comment: Okay and do I have to set that in my code or do I have to do that in my SQL DB? :S Sorry if it is a stupid question but I'm a little new to ASP.NET I only had a few lessons..

Comment: I now have:` string sqlOpdracht = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT ASP.NET Boogschieten Final t_ScoreToevoegen ON; INSERT INTO t_ScoreToevoegen(ID, Voornaam, Achternaam, Boog, Categorie, Datum, Score, Afstand) values (@ID ,@Voornaam, @Achternaam, @Boog, @Categorie, @Datum, @Score, @Afstand); SET IDENTITY_INSERT ASP.NET Boogschieten Final t_ScoreToevoegen OFF";` In my code but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Ok - get rid of that bit of code - wasn't sure if it would work.

Comment: You let SQL set your ID. In SQL when designing the table set the ID as an Int and as a primary key and auto-increment. Google how to do that if you're not sure..

Comment: I did that all before when I created my table.

Comment: Do some research on debugging your sql commands. You must have an exception somewhere.

Comment: Oke I'll do that. Thanks for your help!